# work with session and cookies in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-cxf

i am using component camel-cxf. I want to try to implement the following user authentication scheme:

1. there is a soap method **Login** with user and password fields
2. in the camel processor user-password check occurs
3. in the camel processor create session and set-cookies in response
4. the next time saop calls, the cookie with the session is checked and the request is executed
5. soap method **Logout** destroy session

I could not find information on how to work with the session and cookies in apache camel

Answer (score 0):

The stuff you describe it **not at all Camels business**.

- Authentication of SOAP requests is done with [WS-Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) (WSS). See the [CXF docs](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html) for its excellent WSS support.
- HTTP stuff like sessions and cookies are probably also handled in CXF

If you use a Camel route as a consumer for a CXF SOAP endpoint, Camel normally gets the converted Java object of the request content. All HTTP and SOAP stuff is handled by CXF and Camel doesn't need to know anything about this.